# Is $\mathbb{R}$ the only complete ordered Abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that the field of real numbers is the only complete, ordered field in the sense that any field satisfying these properties is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,<)$.

**Question 1.** Is it true that any complete, ordered Abelian group is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R},+,<)$? If not, is there an example of a complete, ordered Abelian group $(G,+,<)$ which is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

I am using the following definition of complete: A partially ordered set $(P,\leq)$ is complete if each subset $E\subseteq P$ which is bounded above has a least upper bound in $P$. This is modeled after the completeness axiom for $\mathbb{R}$, but I can't find a good source for this more general definition.

**Edit 1.** It is false. A counterexample is $\mathbb{Z}$. It is complete since any subset has a maximum, and ordered as usual,  but not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

**Question 2.** What if we require $G$ to be "dense" in the following sense?

$$\forall a,b\in G, \quad \{g\in G\mid a<g<b\}\neq\emptyset$$

Does this additional condition imply $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

**Edit 2.** It is true. It was shown the only complete ordered Abelian groups are $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, and the "dense" condition leaves only $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Do you mean "totally ordered" with "complete ordered"?

Comment: No. $\Bbb Z$ is also complete (with the usual metric).

Comment: @Dietrich "Complete ordered" i.e. both complete and totally ordered

Comment: I am using "complete" like the completeness axiom for the real numbers. Shouldn't it work on any partially ordered set?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think they mean "complete *as a linear order*."

Comment: @M.Nestor FTI - I deleted the 'counterexample' question. It was too unwieldy maintaining two posts with updates. Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2963140/432081 - you can put any work you have there if you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are in fact only two complete ordered nontrivial Abelian groups (up to isomorphism): $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. The former is complete for a silly reason, namely that every nonempty bounded-above set has a *maximal* element (not just a unique supremum); the latter is the interesting one

*(What about e.g. the group of integer multiples of ${1\over 2}$? That's just $\mathbb{Z}$ again, up to isomorphism.)*

The proof goes roughly as follows (letting $G$ be our nontrivial complete ordered Abelian group):

- First we show that $G$ is *Archimedean*: fixing any positive element $a$, for every $g$ in the group there is some natural number $n$ such that $a+...+a$ ($n$ times) is greater than $g$.
- Now we ask, is there a minimal positive element in $G$? If so, we can show that $G\cong \mathbb{Z}$.
- We're now left with the case where there is no minimal positive element, and we want to show that $G\cong\mathbb{R}$. Fix some positive element $a\in G$, and let $A$ be the set of **rational multiples of $a$**: that is, $$A=\{g\in G:\exists k,l\in\mathbb{Z}(ka=lg)\},$$ where multiplication of a *group element* $h$ by an *integer* $m$ is defined as follows: if $m=0$ then $m\cdot h=e$ (the identity of $G$); if $m>0$ then $m\cdot h=h+...+h$ ($m$ times); and if $m<0$ then $m\cdot h$ is the inverse of $\vert m\vert \cdot h$.
- Having defined $A$ as above, we show that there is a natural injection $i$ of $A$ into $\mathbb{Q}$; in fact, $i$ is the unique embedding of $A$ into $\mathbb{Q}$ as ordered Abelian groups.
- Now we don't know a priori that the image of $i$ is all of $\mathbb{Q}$ - why should there be something in $G$ which is "a third of $a$"? However, we *can* show that the image of $i$ is *dense* in $\mathbb{R}$. Now using completeness, the Dedekind cut construction, and the Archimedean-ness of $G$, we can in fact extend $i$ to a (unique!) isomorphism between $G$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks! This "completely" answers my question.

Comment: Thank Noah! Only thing left is if it is easier to define multiplication in the semigroup or group. References/links?

Comment: @CopyPasteIt I don't really understand what you're asking; are you just asking how we define multiplication etc. via Dedekind cuts? (Note that that's not the question here.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber The bijective automorphisms of the reals (or magnitudes) can be used. Gotta show that it is a commutative group.

Comment: @CopyPasteIt I have no idea what you're asking here, and it seems unrelated to the actual question at hand (which is simply to classify the complete ordered Abelian groups up to isomorphism). Nowhere is the commutativity of any automorphism group being used at all.

Comment: I'll ask a new question when I get a chance.

Comment: Actually there's a third complete ordered abelian group: The trivial group. It is obviously abelian, it is totally ordered (because every one-element set is trivially totally ordered), and it is order-complete (because the only non-empty set has both a maximum and a minimum, which both are its only element).

Comment: @celtschk I just saw this, and have edited to address it!

Comment: What if we drop the commutativity hypothesis? A totally ordered dense and complete group is isomorphic to the reals?