# Relaxing the hypotheses of the theorem that any complete ordered field is isomorphic to the real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, ring-isomorphism

One of the central theorems in real analysis states that any complete ordered field $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$. Here, I mean "complete" in the sense of the least upper bound property, but I am open to the possibility that by considering a different form of the completeness axiom (e.g. Cauchy-completeness), my question might have a more interesting answer.

What I am wondering about is whether we can relax the hypotheses placed on $X$, since most of the obvious ways don't work:

- If we drop the assumption that $X$ is *complete*, then the conclusion
  no longer follows: $\mathbb Q$ is an ordered field, but it is
  certainly not isomorphic to $\mathbb R$.
- If we drop the assumption that $X$ is a *field*, and replace it with
  the assumption that $X$ is an ordered set, then again the conclusion
  no longer follows: the empty set is a complete ordered set! (And there are other non-trivial examples, such as the [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)).)
- The assumption that $X$ is *ordered* cannot, by itself, be dropped, since we need $X$ to be ordered to make sense of any of the forms of the completeness axiom.

There is a [positive result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2964961/is-mathbbr-the-only-complete-ordered-abelian-group): up to an isomorphism, the only complete ordered *abelian groups* are the trivial group, the integers, and the real numbers. But note that in a way this makes our job harder: this means that there is a complete ordered commutative ring which is *not* isomorphic to $\mathbb R$, namely the integers.

> **Question:** Is there a non-trivial way of relaxing the hypotheses on $X$ in such a manner that it still follows that $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$?

It should be noted that to change the hypotheses, we might also have to change the type of isomorphism being considered.

Comment: How about "complete ordered *nontrivial divisible* abelian group" as a hypothesis? It's also easy to prove that $(\mathbb{R};<)$ is the unique-up-to-isomorphism complete *separable* nonempty linear order without endpoints.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Those both look like interesting answers, thank you! I didn't expect it to be possible to characterise $\mathbb R$ just with the relation $\le$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:

- $(\mathbb{R};+)$ is up to isomorphism the unique *nontrivial divisible* completely orderable abelian group.
- $(\mathbb{R};<)$ is up to isomorphism the unique *nonempty* complete *separable* linear order *without endpoints*.

Interestingly, a slight tweak of that second definition takes us into serious set theory: $\mathsf{ZFC}$ alone cannot decide whether every nonempty dense complete linear order without endpoints *with the countable chain condition* is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R};<)$. A linear order satisfies the c.c.c. iff it has no uncountable family of pairwise-disjoint nontrivial open intervals. This question is [Suslin's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin%27s_problem), and its solution(?) required the introduction of **iterated forcing** by Solovay and Tennenbaum.