# Direct construction of the real numbers using only the integers (c.f. Eudoxus reals)

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, real-numbers, binary

Let the natural numbers $\Bbb N = \{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$ and the integers $\Bbb Z$ be given.

We define a function $\gamma: \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ by

$$   
    \gamma(n) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        \frac{n}{2} , & \text{when }\; n \text{ is even}\\
        \frac{n-1}{2}, & \text{when }\;  n \text{ is odd}\\
        \end{array}\right\} 
$$

A [binary relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) $R$ on $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$ is said to be a *r-locator* if it satisfies the following four properties:

$$\tag 1 \text{The domain of } R \text{ is equal to } \Bbb N$$
$$\tag 2 \text{For every integer } n \ge 0, \text{ if } nRm \text{ then } (n+1)R2m$$
$$\tag 3 \text{For every integer } n \gt 0, \text{ if } nRm \text{ then } (n-1)R\gamma(m)$$
$$\tag 4 \text{For every integer } n \ge 0, \text{ the image } R(n) \text{ is bounded above}$$

We can associate to any r-locator a function $\; \mathtt M(R): \Bbb N \to \Bbb Z$ by writing

$$\tag 5 \mathtt M(R): n \mapsto \text{Max}\big(R(n)\big)$$

A function $\alpha: \Bbb N \to \Bbb Z$ is said to be a *binary tick specification* if it satisfies the following two properties,

$\tag 6 \text{For every } n \in \Bbb N, \; \big [ \, \alpha(n+1) = 2\alpha(n) \text{ or } \alpha(n+1) = 2\alpha(n) + 1 \,\big ]$

$\tag 7 \text{For every } N \in \Bbb N \text{ there exists a } n  \ge N \text{ such that } \alpha(n+1) = 2\alpha(n)$

Lemma 1: If $R$ is a r-locator then the function $\alpha = \mathtt M(R)$ satisfies $\text{(6)}$.

In general, when a function $\rho$ satisfies only $\text{(6)}$, there is a *fix*:

Find the smallest $K$ such that for all $k \ge K$, $\rho(k)$ is odd. Then redefine the function by writing $\rho^{'}(k) = \rho(k) + 1$ for $k \ge K$. Also, if $K$ has a predecessor, define $\rho^{'}(K-1) = \rho(K-1) + 1$ and retain the remaining $\rho$ definitions (if any) for $\rho^{'}$. The new function $\rho^{'}$ satisfies both $\text{(6)}$ and $\text{(7)}$.

Example: $\rho = (-1,-1,-1,\dots)$ satisfies $\text{(6)}$ but not $\text{(7)}$. Applying the fix, $\rho^{'} = (0,0,0,\dots)$.

Lemma 2: Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two binary tick specifications. The smallest subset $[R(\alpha,\beta)]$ of $\Bbb N \times \Bbb Z$ containing the graph of $\alpha + \beta$ (pointwise addition) and satisfying $\text{(1)}$ thru $\text{(3)}$ also satisfies $\text{(4)}$.

If necessary we apply the fix to $\mathtt M([R(\alpha,\beta)])$ and define the addition of the two specifications,

$$\tag 8  \alpha + \beta = \mathtt M([R(\alpha,\beta)])$$

giving another binary tick specification.

Let $\Bbb B$ denote the set of all binary tick specifications with this binary operation $+$.

Theorem 3: The structure $(\Bbb B, +)$ is a commutative group. Moreover, it is isomorphic to $(\Bbb R, +)$.

Example: Pointwise addition of
$\quad +\frac{1}{4} = (0,0,1,2,4,\dots)$
$\quad -\frac{1}{4} = (-1,-1,-1,-2,-4,\dots)$
gives
$\quad \quad \;\, = (-1,-1,0,0,0,\dots)$

If this sum generates the r-locator $R$, then $\mathtt M(R)$ returns $(0,0,0,0,0,\dots)$, as expected.

**My Work**

I've been working through some of the theory details, but felt it would be beneficial to present these rough ideas now rather than attempting to supply complete proofs.

> Does this theory hold together?

The motivation for this work came from the desire to find a model for Tarski's axiomatic formulation of the real numbers; see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963140/translating-tarskis-axiomatization-logic-of-mathbb-r-to-the-theory-of-magnit).

---

The exposition of the above theory is a direct route to the real numbers that does not require the construction of the rational numbers. Nor the definition of a limit or floor function. However, the following relations hold true:

Every $\alpha$ specifies a real number $a$ as follows,

## $\quad a = {\displaystyle \lim _{n \to +\infty} \frac{\alpha(n)}{2^n}}$

The inverse mapping is given by

## $\quad \alpha(n) = \lfloor a 2^n \rfloor$

Comment: What do you mean by "structure"?  You mean as groups?  Monoids?  Sets?  What?

Comment: @Randall Yes. The additive group structures.

Comment: Where are the parentheses in condition (1)?  Is it "for every $n$ (blah X or blah Y)" or is it "(for every $n$ blah X) or (for every $n$ blah Y)"?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to construct all the real numbers in $[0, 1]$ using just one number, namely $\frac{2}{3}$. It goes as follows. The binary expansion of $\frac{2}{3}$ is $0.10101010\cdots$. Any real number in $[0, 1]$ can be obtained by performing an infinite permutation on these binary digits. For instance $1 = 0.1111111\cdots$ is obtained by moving all the $1$'s to the left.